# how to add next button in number pad keyboard in ios for all textfield and navigate to next

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have one design screen in which there are multiple  `UITextfield`(almost 30)  and all field requires NumberPad next keyboard  and when clicked on next button then automatically it should move to next `UITextfield`.I need generic solution for all textfields.

Comment: Check the discussion under this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192303/how-to-add-a-done-button-to-numpad-keyboard-in-ios), i think it may help you.

Answer (score 2):

Please add this into your project[IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager).Add below code in your `appdelgate`

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

      IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

      return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also TPKeyboardAvoiding. Its working for me and easy to integration. For more details given below link...

[TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)

Answer (score 0):

Directly there is no way to have return key with numb pad, but there are other solutions
1) Customize your own keyboard.
2) Add next button who appear along with keyboard above it and dismissed with keyboard. In that button action you can put the logic of dismissing keyboard for the current textfield and choose next textfield and make keyboard appear for it.

Comment: Can you give me code for  custom keyboard with next button

Comment: @NeerajIOS : Refer tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/ to create custom keyboard using extension and allow to use it for your app. Set this custom keyboard as your inputview for textfields.